# Anybody recognize this script?

Tags: database

I've got a consulting IT request to examine a dataset for a court case. Suffice to say, I can't provide a whole lot of detail.

At the top of the dataset, there is what appears to be the query that generated the dataset, but it's in a format I've never seen. It seems fairly easy to figure out what the query is selecting, but I was wondering whether anyone here was able to identify what system is running this script.

Here's the script, de-identified:

```
SMSLIST OPTIONS PAGE LENGTH 055 MARGINS 001 00132 LIMIT 01000
 LINE SPACING 0
REQUEST TITLE 'TITLE'
COLUMNS "OBSV PERF DATE" HEADING 'DATE'
 , "OBSV PERF TIME" HEADING 'TIME'
 , "OBSV CD"
 , "OBSV CD NAME" HEADING 'OBSERVATION'
 , "OBSV DSPLY VAL" HEADING 'VALUE'
 , "OBSV VAL STS CD" HEADING 'STATUS'
ORDERED BY "OBSV CD" , "OBSV PERF DATE" , "OBSV PERF TIME"
WHERE (  "PT NO"  EQ (XXXXXXXX)  AND  "OBSV CD GRP NAME"  IN ('VITALS+WT','I/O'
) )
```

Comment: Hmmm. Looks like RPG maybe.  But what do I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was had some time this morning and love a challenge so I tried to give you a hand. It looks like it is the query language for something called "AD HOC Wizard Report Builder", here is a link to a page from their manual where similar content is shown: [Detail List Report Sample](http://www.mercuridata.com/helpsample/Chapter06/Detail_List_Report_Sample_1.htm).

There were also a lot of hits on some UNC list server, but none of the pages were available.

Sorry, that's all I could find, but maybe that helps a bit.

Comment: Wow! I tried googling this stuff myself, but to no avail! Thanks for the time and effort. How did you find it, if I may ask?

Comment: Googled "smslist options page" and then poked around a bit. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you're still working on this a year later, but I believe it's for Siemens Medical Solutions.